# NextJS conditional classes with css modules gives console warning

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on NextJS project and I need to have 2 classes on a element but one of them is conditionally added. I'm using css modules.

I know how to add 2 classes - `` className={`${styles.class1} ${styles.class2}`} `` - and this works fine, but when I want to add class2 conditionally I get the warning in the console:

```
Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `className`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: className="false" or className={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with className={condition && value}, pass className={condition ? value : undefined} instead.
```

Here's me code:

```
import styles from './styles.module.css'

<div className={`${styles.class1} ${isShowLinks ? styles.class2 : undefined}`}>
  Code here
</div>
```

I also tried with {isShowLinks && styles.class2} but I get same warning in console.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you certain that's the line triggering the warning you're seeing in the console? It doesn't look like the expression you have in the `className` prop would ever return `false`.

Comment: good point, error was in className={router.asPath === href && styles.active}